# Revoking anonymous access to Artifactory

Tags: security, permissions, user

I've inherited an Artifactory server, and there is sensitive information stored in some of the repositories that shouldn't be accessible to a non-authenticated user. 
According to [this link in the JFrog Knowledge base](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-how-can-non-authenticated-users-download-resources-from-my-artifactory-server/), this should be as easy as unchecking the checkbox - but after doing this, I am still able to download content anonymously. Apparently anonymous access was previously allowed, because the anonymous user exists, and I can't delete the user.

I'm using Artifactory OSS 6.7.0 rev 60700900.

Is this a bug or have I overlooked something? Is this intended behavior designed to get my organization to pay for Artifactory?

How can I ensure only authenticated users can download content?